# How to use local variables in closures during performDrop

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, closures

I'm working my way through the Stanford CS193P Course on iTunesU. Stuck on this one part - There's one section where the instructor has the following comment:

> When a drop happens, you'll have to collect both the aspect ratio (from 
>     the UIImage) and the URL before you can add an item. You could do this 
>     straightforwardly with a couple of local variables that are captured by 
>     the closures used to load up the drag and drop data

I assume this to mean that I have to update my model item in the performDrop method of the UICollectionViewDropDelegate protocol. Therefore I will have to call loadObject for both the NSURL item and the UIImage item. However, since the completion handlers for loadObject are off the main thread, I don't have access to the same local variable for both. Therefore if I first load the UIImage, get the aspect ratio, and save it to a local variable in the performDrop method, that variable is still empty when I call loadObject on the URL, which is when I create the model based on the URL and the aspect ratio. I tried nesting the loadObject calls, but the 2nd call was not firing. My code is below:

```
let placeholderContext = coordinator.drop(item.dragItem, to: 
UICollectionViewDropPlaceholder(insertionIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, reuseIdentifier: placeholderCellReuseIdentifier))
            var aspectRatio: [CGFloat] = []

            item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (provider, error) in
                if var image = provider as? UIImage {
                    aspectRatio.append(image.size.width / image.size.height)
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self, completionHandler: { (provider, error) in
                    print(provider)
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    print("load urls in completion")
                })
                }
            }
            print("main thread: \(aspectRatio)")

            item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self) { (provider, error) in
                print("loaded urls")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let url = provider as? URL {
                        placeholderContext.commitInsertion(dataSourceUpdates: { (insertionIndexPath) in
                    self.galleryItems.items.insert(GalleryItem(imageURL: url.imageURL, aspectRatio: 1.0), at: insertionIndexPath.item)
                        })
                    } else {
                        placeholderContext.deletePlaceholder()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Am I misguided here or is there something simple I am missing? How can I get the aspect ratio from loading the UIImage first, and then use that in the URL load object completion handler, in the way as is described in the homework?